# How to refactor two Java methods into one?

Tags: java

What is the best way to refactor the following two Java methods into one:

```
public List<AnotherClassA> doSomething(String aString, Integer anInteger) {
    List<AnotherClassA> listOfClassAObjects;
    if(condition) {
        aClassAInstanceVariable = new ClassAConstructor(aString, anInteger);
    }
    else {
        aClassAInstanceVariable = getClassAInstanceVariableFromSomewhere();
    }
    listOfClassAObjects.add(aClassAInstanceVariable);
    return listOfClassAObjects;
}

public List<AnotherClassB> doSomething(String aString, Integer anInteger) {
    List<AnotherClassB> listOfClassAObjects;
    if(condition) {
        aClassBInstanceVariable = new ClassBConstructor(aString, anInteger);
    }
    else {
        aClassBInstanceVariable = getClassBInstanceVariableFromSomewhere();
    }
    listOfClassAObjects.add(aClassBInstanceVariable);
    return listOfClassAObjects;
}
```

The differences:

- The return types are different
- The constructors (ClassAConstructor and ClassBContractor) to construct the new object are different
- the getClassXInstanceVariableFromSomewhere() methods are different

Comment: May be you should look at the visitor pattern if you have many anotherClass

Comment: also your query method (getClassXInstanceVariableFromSomewhere()) is different.

Comment: there seems to be a code duplication in both methods. why not put common code in the if block inside a single method or move it to a utility static class. this way you can reuse your code

Comment: `listOfClassAObjects.add` will crash, because `listOfClassAObjects` is not initialized.

Comment: @vikeng21 yes, just edited and added that difference. so, now there are 3 differences for the two methods

Comment: @dasblinkenlight never mind it will crash. the actual code is much more complicated. i had to simplify it to ask the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a generic method, with a bit of reflection help to create instance of type `T`. You would need to pass `Class<T>` as argument:

```
public <T> List<T> doSomething(Class<T> clazz, String aString, Integer anInteger) {
    List<T> listOfClassObjects;
    if(condition) {
        Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class, Integer.class);
        aClassInstanceVariable = constructor.newInstance(aString, anInteger);
    }
    else {
        aClassInstanceVariable = getClassTInstanceVariableFromSomewhere();
    }
    listOfClassObjects.add(aClassInstanceVariable);
    return listOfClassObjects;
}
```

And handle the appropriate exceptions.

Comment: In this case, the instance variable would have to be Object since it's the only thing that could hold a pure generic type. And getClassTInstanceVariableFromSomewhere would also need to be generified.

Answer (score 0):

There was obviously some information lost when stripping the code down to the "dummy code" suitable for asking the question here. At the moment, there is no reason to put the objects into a list, because there is only a single object in the list - and it is in general not clear where the list comes from. Additionally, knowing the nature of the `condition` that is tested for might be helpful. It is also not clear whether the `getClassBInstanceVariableFromSomewhere` method can somehow be parameterized.

However, what the method actually does is providing an instance of `ClassA` or `ClassB`. One standard way of factoring out constructor calls is the factory pattern. Considering the fact that possibly (depending on the "condition") no instance is created, one could call this a special case of a [Supplier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) as in the Java 8 functional package, or in fact, simply an implementation of the [BiFunction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) interface.

Depending on the *real* code, several application patterns would then be possible

```
List<ClassA> list = Arrays.asList(functionA.apply(aString, anInteger));

// Or
List<ClassA> list = Arrays.asList(
    condition ? functionA.apply(aString, anInteger) : supplierA.get());

// Or (if you wanted to return a list directly)
List<ClassA> list = functionA.apply(aString, anInteger));
```