# How to use generics to combine these two methods Into one?

Tags: java, generics

I know a lot of Java Generics questions like this already exist such as ([How to refactor two Java methods into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942795/how-to-refactor-two-java-methods-into-one)), but I guess I just need to see it with my own, simpler function --  with an example of how to call it, to completely understand java generics...I apologize and thank you in advance!

All I know Is that I will probably need to use instanceof, and Class.forName to handle the different return types (and possibly add a second argument for the desiredClass, or can this be deduced somehow without adding the second argument?)

```
public static <T> T getSanitizedURI(String theUrl, Class desiredReturnType) {
}
```

but then what?

```
public static URI getSanitizedURI(String theUrl) {
        URI sanitizedUri = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            sanitizedUri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sanitizedUri;
    }

    public static String getSanitizedURIString(String theUrl) {
        String sanitizedUrl = theUrl;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
            sanitizedUrl = uri.toASCIIString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sanitizedUrl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is not a good use case for generics. If the user wants a `String` they can use the method that returns a `String`. If they want a `URI` they can use the method that returns a `URI`. Generics would be more appropriate if it is not possible to determine at the time of writing the method all the different types that the method could be used for, or if the method is to be used for lots of different types.

However, you can reduce the code duplication as follows

```
public static String getSanitizedURIString(String theUrl) {
    return getSanitizedURI(theUrl).toASCIIString();
}
```

Note that this will throw a `NullPointerException` if `getSanitizedURI` returns `null`. You may prefer to handle this case differently, such as returning `theUrl` as suggested by @ViacheslavVedenin.

Comment: Add don't forget that getSanitizedURI(theUrl) can returns null, so better use URL url = getSanitizedURI(theUrl); return url != null? url.toASCIIString(): theUrl;

Comment: Thank you for the response, and in practice I agree.  However, for the purpose of getting my brain to understand generics, how could this be done?  Ill attach two more methods that might be a better use case for generics.

Comment: @NewJava If you really want to use generics, it should be `public static <T> T getSanitizedURI(String theUrl, Class<T> desiredReturnType)`. Then you can do `if (desiredReturnType == String.class) return (T) someString; else if (desiredReturnType == URI.class return (T) someURI; else throw new IllegalArgumentException();`.

Comment: @NewJava I'm not sure what you mean.  For the purpose of getting your brain to understand generics, this is not an appropriate place to use generics.

Comment: @NewJava In general I consider it an anti-pattern to make the return type of a method generic (i.e. have a `T` in it) when the argument list doesn't. So signatures like `public static <T> List<T> getList(String name)` are a really bad idea. Since you are not passing anything that depends on `T` into the method, there is no way that the method could possibly return what you want without an compromising type safety. For example you could write `List<Integer> list = MyClass.<Integer>getList("foo");` or `List<String> list = MyClass.<String>getList("foo")`. It compiles but makes no sense at all.

Comment: @NewJava The reason it makes no sense is because `getList("foo")` cannot possibly be both a list with strings in it and a list with `Integer` in it. If you try my code in the example four comments above you will see that the casts to `(T)` give warnings. These warnings are a strong clue that this kind of thing is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and examples!